# What is "a" in the execution environment "I" in the yellow paper?

Tags: yellow-paper

Excerpt from chapter 7, "Contract creation":

[image: Yellow Paper Chapter 7]

All symbols in the picture above have been clearly defined prior to chapter 7. I couldn't find though a specific explanation for what `a` stands for, as per the inclusion in `{s,a}` and `Ia = a` in definition 83 and 84, respectively.

It is explained that `I` is the execution environment - and that's cool! We could consequently deduce that `a` should be the account being created, but I cannot ascertain this because `a` has only been vaguely specified in the definition of the world state. That is, `σ[a]` (sigma of a).

Is `a` the resultant account of the contract creation call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bad, I overlooked definition 77:

[image: Yellow Paper Definition 77]

Further down the rabbit hole in section 9.3, "Execution Environment":

[image: Yellow Paper Section 9.3]